# Problems converting a INI based configuration into YAML

Tags: zend-form

Greetings to all.

I am working on a project that uses Zend_Config to create forms. I am working on broadening my knowledge base and have hit a snag.

I have a form config file in ini format that works fine. I would like to convert that form configuration into a YAML based file. I attempted to write the conversion myself, and though I accounted for everything. As this is my first journey into yaml, I need help to see what is wrong.

The ini file that works is here:

```
    [production]
    ;General From Meta Data
    logon.form.action = "/customers/plogin"
    logon.form.method="post"
    logon.form.id="loginform"
    ;Form Element Prefix Data
    logon.form.elementPrefixPath.decorator.prefix = "Elite_Decorator_"
    logon.form.elementPrefixPath.decorator.path = "Elite/Decorator/"
    logon.form.elementPrefixPath.decorator.type = "decorator"
    logon.form.elementPrefixPath.validate.prefix = "Elite_Validate_"
    logon.form.elementPrefixPath.validate.path = "Elite/Validate/"
    logon.form.elementPrefixPath.validate.type = "validate"
    ;Form Element - email
    logon.form.elements.email.type = "text"
    logon.form.elements.email.options.required = "true"
    logon.form.elements.email.options.label = "Email"
    logon.form.elements.email.options.decorators.composite.decorator = "Composite"
    logon.form.elements.email.options.validators.strlen.validator = "StringLength"
    logon.form.elements.email.options.validators.strlen.options.min="2"
    logon.form.elements.email.options.validators.strlen.options.max="50"
    ;Form Element - Password
    logon.form.elements.password.type = "password"
    logon.form.elements.password.options.required = "true"
    logon.form.elements.password.options.label = "Password"
    logon.form.elements.password.options.decorators.composite.decorator = "Composite"
    logon.form.elements.password.options.validators.strlen.validator = "StringLength"
    logon.form.elements.password.options.validators.strlen.options.min="2"
    logon.form.elements.password.options.validators.strlen.options.max="20"
    ;Form Element - Submit
    logon.form.elements.submit.type = "submit"
    logon.form.elements.submit.options.label = "Logon"
    ;Form Display Group 1
    logon.form.displaygroups.group1.name = "logon"
    logon.form.displaygroups.group1.options.legend = "Please Login to your Account"
    logon.form.displaygroups.group1.options.decorators.formelements.decorator = "FormElements"
    logon.form.displaygroups.group1.options.decorators.fieldset.decorator = "Fieldset"  
    logon.form.displaygroups.group1.options.decorators.fieldset.options.style = "width:375px;"
    logon.form.displaygroups.group1.elements.email = "email"
    logon.form.displaygroups.group1.elements.password = "password"
    logon.form.displaygroups.group1.elements.submit = "submit"
```

And my YAML translation:

```
    production:
           logon:
    form:
        action: /customers/plogin
        method: post
        id: loginform
        elementPrefixPath:
            decorator:
                prefix: Elite_Decorator_
                path: Elite/Decorator/
                type: decorator
            validate:
                prefix: Elite_Validate_
                path: Elite/Validate/
                type: validate
        elements:
            email:
                type: text
                options:
                    required: true
                    label: Email
                    decorators:
                        composite:
                            decorator: Composite
                    validators:
                        strlen:
                            validator: StringLength
                            options:
                                min: 2
                                max: 50
            password:
                type: text
                options:
                    required: true
                    label: Password
                    decorators:
                        composite:
                            decorator: Composite
                    validators:
                        strlen:
                            validator: StringLength
                            options:
                                min: 2
                                max: 20
            submit:
                type: submit
                options:
                    label: Logon
        displaygroups:
            group1:
                name: logon
                options:
                    legend: Please login to your account
                    decorators:
                        formelements:
                            decorator: FormElements
                        fieldset:
                            decorator: Fieldset
                            options:
                                style: width:375px; 
                elements:
                    email: email
                    password: password
                    submit: submit
```

The YAML based form only gives me a blank page. Upon investigation, none of the form markup is included in the page that is output. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Troy

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have better indentation in your code:

```
production:
    logon:
        form:
            action: /customers/plogin
            method: post
....
```

Comment: The indentation seems fine, as long as all the children line up there should be no problem. The YAML above parses correctly on the [Online YAML Parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/).